# detect when user scrolls to the bottom not working

Tags: jquery, scroll, window, height

I have been trying to detect when user scrolling hits the bottom

And I have below code.

```
if  ($(window).scrollTop() == ($(document).innerHeight() - $(window).height())){

     alert('22')
}
```

the issue here is, $(window).height() returns the same as $(document).height(), which is bigger than actual window view port.

my screen resultion is about 1280px.

but $(document).height returns 1670 something and so is $(window).height().

so document.height - window.height is always 0

Am I doing something wrong?

Im using Mac OSx Chrome.

Thanks

////////////////////////

window.innerHeight  and document.height  fixed the issue as Sushil suggested

Comment: Have you changed window size? Does the number returned change?

Comment: Also, try $('body').outerHeight();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work;

```
$(window).scroll(function()
{
    if($(window).scrollTop() == $(document).height() - $(window).height())
    {

    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks but I can do simple math. that conditional always returns true because window.height is already the same as document height. so if user scroll 1 px, it returns true

Comment: Hi Sushil, I know how they are supposed to behave but my issue is they aren't at the moment.  $(window).height() doesn't return height of the window.

Comment: then try with native variables like window.innerHeight

Comment: As you saying $(window).height() is equals to $(document).height(). that means alert is coming on scrollTop is 0.

Comment: and yes, without scrolling it alerts   lol.   no idea what's going on but    native variable works correctly !

Answer (score 0):

by this you can get if yuo scrol below some div or HTML object

```
   $(window).scroll(function () {
    if($(window).scrollTop()+ $(window).height() >( $(".photo").offset().top +$(".photo").outerHeight()))
    {
    //YOUR CODE 
    }
  });
```